# SQL Server 2008 Swap single column value inside and out of brackets

Tags: sql-server

Currently has a table column value like below.

```
StudentName

ABC [DEF]

GHI [JKL]

MNO [PQR]
```

And we want to change the StudentName column value to as below.

```
StudentName

DEF [ABC]

JKL [GHI]

PQR [MNO]
```

Do we have SQL function that can swap the value inside and outside the brackets?

Comment: Presumably you want to run an update statement, setting col1=col2, col2=col1.

Comment: that only work if i want swap two columns value, but my request is to swap within one single column value

Comment: I didn't realise that was all one column. In that case, there's other things to consider. Presumably ABC is the surname and DEF is the given name. Is it always just "text text"? What happens with middle names?

Comment: This is just an example. The column didn't only means a person's name, you can treat that as product description. I just want to know what's the method to swap the value outside the bracket and within the bracket.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no special function, that switches parts of the string. You have to manually come up with something like this:

```
SELECT * INTO tbl_Students
FROM (VALUES
('ABC [DEF]'),
('GHI [JKL]'),
('MNO [PQR]')) as x(StudentName);
GO
SELECT * FROM tbl_Students;
GO
UPDATE tbl_Students
SET StudentName =
    REPLACE(RIGHT(StudentName, LEN(StudentName) - CHARINDEX ('[',StudentName)),']',' [')
    + REPLACE(LEFT(StudentName,CHARINDEX ('[',StudentName)-1),' ',']');
GO
SELECT * FROM tbl_Students;
GO
```

Comment: Hmm. Note this will work if the format is always "text [text]", but not if it's like "text text [text]"

Comment: you are correct. in case of more than one space he has to use more complicated logic. I assume it is a student and I've showed him the way to learn. Now he can look how it is done and adjust it to his own situation. If he can't, then probably it is wrong field he is trying to get degree in.

Comment: Thanks Slava, I think your method works for my request.

Comment: ZLK, I think your concern is right, if has more space and text in between then Slava's solution here won't work.

Comment: It also won't work if you have extra brackets in the beginning of the string. You have to have exact business rules and implement code accordingly.

Comment: Oh also one correction on Slava's query, when use RIGHT() the correct query should be RIGHT(StudentName,LEN(StudentName) - CHARINDEX ('[',StudentName))

Comment: Just Fixed it. Thanks again

Comment: Slava, thank you, you give the proper solution here. Cheers